# Review command in paper document class

Tags: document-classes

By chance I saw that the `paper` document class has a `\review` command.
After Googling a bit I was unable to find any useful reference to it.
Can you tell me what is it for?

Comment: if you have texlive or miktex you should be able to go `texdoc paper` and `\review` is described on page 4 (in german)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I saw that googling. Any English ref somewhere?

Comment: No idea, I'd just stick the tex source of the document into google translate:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A manual translation of the paragraph on the `\review` and `\revauthor` commands in the `paper` manual:

> The new command `\review[optional]{author}{title}` is designed for
>   draft reviews. The command takes the author and title of the discussed
>   work. These are typeset as a `\subsubsection`, and included in the
>   table of contents. Optionally, the author of the review can be
>   specified, which then also appears in the table of contents. The
>   starred form `\review*` completely suppresses the toc entry. The
>   command `\revauthor` is useful to sign the review. Just
>   like the usual `\author` command it supports multiple authors, separated with
>   `\and`, and the `\thanks` command.

---

**Note:** From the class definition it appears table of contents entries are only generated when including the paper in a document with `\documentclass[journal]{paper}` or `\documentclass{journal}` (which internally is converted to `\documentclass[journal]{paper}`).